# Getting an error trying to make the range of a while loop above 10

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object with different cars, I am relaying these cars to HTML with a loop, however whenever I try to make the condition (`<=`) above 10, it throws an error.

This is for a test I am making with a cars site.

Here is my function:

```
function dispCars(){
    let output = "";
    let i = 1;
    let maxNum = 10;
    while (i <= maxNum){
      const carName = cars["c" + i].name;
      const carMake = cars["c" + i].make;
      const carPrice = cars["c" + i].price;
      console.log(carName);
      output += "<div class='column'><div style='padding:0px;' class='ui segment'><a href='#'><img class='card-icon' src='../src/media/cars/" + i + ".jpg'></a><a href='#'><p class='heading'>"+ carMake + " " + carName + "</a><span class='price'>" + carPrice + "</span></p></div></div></div>";
      i++;
    }

    catalogue.innerHTML = output;
}
```

Here is a little bit of JSON:

```
const cars = {
    "c1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sprinter Boxtruck",
        "make": "Mercedes",
        "price": "£500,000",
        "topspeed": "87mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    "c2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "RS4 Avant",
        "make": "Audi",
        "price": "£300,000",
        "topspeed": "101mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    "c3": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "250 GTO",
        "make": "Ferrari",
        "price": "£350,000",
        "topspeed": "92mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    "c4": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Enzo",
        "make": "Ferrari",
        "price": "£3,500,000",
        "topspeed": "130mph",
        "vip": "false"
    }
    ,
    "c5": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "F350 Superduty",
        "make": "Ford",
        "price": "£500,000",
        "topspeed": "80mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    "c6": {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Focus SVT",
        "make": "Ford",
        "price": "£250,000",
        "topspeed": "81mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    "c7": {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Mustang GT",
        "make": "Ford",
        "price": "£800,000",
        "topspeed": "87mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    "c8": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Raptor SVT",
        "make": "Ford",
        "price": "£500,000",
        "topspeed": "70mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    "c9": {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Transit",
        "make": "Ford",
        "price": "£150,000",
        "topspeed": "87mph",
        "vip": "false"
    }
    ,
    "10": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "E-Type",
        "make": "Jaguar",
        "price": "£250,000",
        "topspeed": "87mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    "c11": {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "F-Type",
        "make": "Mercedes",
        "price": "£600,000",
        "topspeed": "99mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    "c12": {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Gallardo",
        "make": "Lamborghini",
        "price": "£2,500,000",
        "topspeed": "111mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
...
```

Here is the error thrown:

```
index.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at dispCars (index.js:29)
    at index.js:40
```

My expected result is for the output to correspond with the input, e.g. if I make the condition `<=12` I want it to relay 12 cars to HTML. It works like that perfectly well when the condition is below 10.
Actual result is an error thrown.

Comment: how many cars do you have in the object? would an array not serve better?

Comment: We need to see the entire JSON in order to help. There probably aren’t enough nested objects.

Comment: your json has less than 10 items in it

Comment: There's no JSON in the question. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: The entire JSON goes up to 52 cars, but I will show you the first 12 as that is how much it would need to work. Edited post.

Comment: `"10": {` should be `"c10": {`

Comment: An array would work much better in this case.

Comment: as @MoshFeu said no `c` in `c10`

Comment: Great catch mate! Thank you, I didn't notice that, apologies.

Comment: @tzcoding Is there a reason you aren’t using an array in this case?

Comment: No problem :) It happens.

Comment: Try using `i < Object.keys(cars).length`

Comment: If you need to use that object and not array, you can use `object.values`, like this: https://jsbin.com/yuzasas/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

Use an *array*, not an object:

```
const cars = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Sprinter Boxtruck",
        "make": "Mercedes",
        "price": "£500,000",
        "topspeed": "87mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "RS4 Avant",
        "make": "Audi",
        "price": "£300,000",
        "topspeed": "101mph",
        "vip": "false"
    },
    // ...
];
```

and then use a `for` loop, a `for-of` loop, `forEach`, `map`, or some other [array looping construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476). Since you're using ES2015+ features, `for-of` would be the minimal change. You can even use destructuring and perhaps a template literal:

```
function dispCars(){
    let output = "";
    for (const [index, {name, make, price}] of cars.entries()) {
      output += `<div class='column'><div style='padding:0px;' class='ui segment'><a href='#'><img class='card-icon' src='../src/media/cars/${index + 1}.jpg'></a><a href='#'><p class='heading'>${make} ${name}</a><span class='price'>${price}</span></p></div></div></div>`;
    }
    catalogue.innerHTML = output;
}
```

but I'd probably go a bit further and use `map` and `join`:

```
function dispCars(){
    catalogue.innerHTML = cars.map((index, {name, make, price}) =>
      `<div class='column'><div style='padding:0px;' class='ui segment'><a href='#'><img class='card-icon' src='../src/media/cars/${index + 1}.jpg'></a><a href='#'><p class='heading'>${make} ${name}</a><span class='price'>${price}</span></p></div></div></div>`
    ).join("");
}
```